# Jenkins CLI failing with timeout

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to run a groovy script via Jenkins CLI but it fails in the middle of the execution and looks like it to be a timeout issue. I have tried changing the port to fixed and random and it didn't work as well. I am having Jenkins 2.289.3

```
Jan 13, 2022 2:44:32 PM hudson.cli.PlainCLIProtocol$FramedReader run
WARNING: null
hudson.cli.DiagnosedStreamCorruptionException
Read back:
Read ahead:
Diagnosis problem:
    java.io.IOException: Premature EOF
        at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAheadBlocking(ChunkedInputStream.java:565)
        at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAhead(ChunkedInputStream.java:609)
        at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:696)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3454)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3447)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3435)
        at io.jenkins.cli.shaded.org.apache.commons.io.input.ProxyInputStream.read(ProxyInputStream.java:62)
        at hudson.cli.FlightRecorderInputStream$1.run(FlightRecorderInputStream.java:62)
        at hudson.cli.FlightRecorderInputStream.analyzeCrash(FlightRecorderInputStream.java:85)
        at hudson.cli.PlainCLIProtocol$FramedReader.run(PlainCLIProtocol.java:158)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Premature EOF
```

Comment: Have you managed to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I've been running into the exact same thing.
I'm running jenkins-2.322-1.1
Seems to get triggered when output is being piped from another job that a parent job called with the CLI.
Also, the CLI called job has a lot of output - it's performing the compile step of a multi-stage build.
So:

1. Streamed output of child job in parent job.
2. Much console output of child job.

This issue definitely got introduced somewhere with one of the new releases because this was never a problem with an older version I used to use running the same jobs.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this ?